Delete Tasks using Django framework
Im currently creating a todo list project using the Django web framework and i currently have an issue with deleting tasks of the webpage. My issue is that i don't know and can't find suitable code to perform the action of deleting a task from the webpage. This is what the webpage looks like: todo list.
I believe my issue is contained in the views.py file:
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages as django_messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login, logout as auth_logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import RegisterForm, CreateTask
from .models import Task  # Import Task model

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateTask(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreateTask()
    
    tasks = Task.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:10]  # Query Task model correctly
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'tasks': tasks,
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)

def delete_task(request, id):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=id)
    task.delete()
    return redirect('home')

@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    django_messages.success(request, 'Logged out successfully')
    return redirect("introduction")  # Redirect to a valid URL name

def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth_login(request, user)
            django_messages.success(request, 'Login successful')
            return redirect('home')  # Replace 'index' with your actual URL name
        else:
            django_messages.error(request, 'Login failed')
    return render(request, "login.html")

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            django_messages.success(request, 'Registration successful')
            return redirect('home')  # Replace 'index' with your actual URL name
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def delete_user(request, username):
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username=username)
        u.delete()
        django_messages.success(request, "User is deleted")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        django_messages.error(request, "User doesn't exist")
    except Exception as e:
        django_messages.error(request, f"Error deleting user: {e}")
    return redirect("introduction")  # Redirect to a valid URL name

def introduction(request):
    return render(request, 'introduction.html')

These are the files i also used to create the project
models.py:
from django.db import models

class Task(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.subject} - ({self.created_at})"`

forms.py:
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Task

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class CreateTask(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['subject', 'description']

urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path("login/", views.user_login, name="login"),
    path("logout/", views.user_logout, name="logout"),
    path("introduction/", views.introduction, name="introduction"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("delete-user/<str:username>", views.delete_user, name="delete-user")
]

home.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Todo List</h1>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Post Task</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
            {% for task in tasks %}
                <li>{{ task.subject }} - {{ task.description }} (Created at: {{ task.created_at }})</li>
            {% empty %}
                <li>No tasks available</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="user-settings">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a class="link-logout" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                <a class="link-delete" href="{% url 'delete-user' username=user.username %}">Delete Account</a>
            {% else %}
                <a class="link-login" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

The code I tried in the views.py file for deleting tasks was:
def delete_task(request, id):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=id)
    task.delete()
    return redirect('home')

But this code didn't work so i am right now struggling with the code i should write to properly delete tasks from the webpage. Does anyone have any suggestions, tips, example code or solutions that can solve this problem?

The issue you mentioned is that the delete_task() function is not working. it is not working because you are not calling the function. I will provide steps to go through.
Go through this:

Define a url to the delete_task() function in urls.py.
In html provide a button for task deletion, in the button give the delete_task() funciton url and pass task_id also along with url.

I hope you understand the concept. If you have any doubts, please let me know. I haven't provided the code because if I did, you might just copy and paste it. That's why I've given you a way to do it by yourself.
